# How do I prevent Django from applying a migration

Tags: python, django, git, migration

I am on a team working on a project using Django. Besides my local dev server, we also have the Test environment and Live environment.
In the process of undoing changes and reverting PR, the test and Live environment databases are out of sync, but the codes are the same.

In our workflow, we merge the feature branch into the test branch, then test branch into master(Live branch)
The local dev server and the test DB have a table column that I need to remove. This column is not in the Live environment db. I make the appropriate change to the model class, generate and apply the migrations and push to test branch. The migration is applied in the test environment.

**My Challenge**

When test is merged to master, Django attempts to apply the migration to remove the column but fails to find the column. Hence, error is thrown.
Is there a way to mark this migration so that on Live DB, Django does not apply it?
Note: I do not have access to the Live Db, otherwise I would have manually added the column to be remove by the migration.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you try to merge it in first place if this migration is just quick patch on test/staging environment, you can still keep it and fake but this would require each new team member probably to do so and makes no sense

Comment: This might work if you added the column as a separate standalone migration. Remove the column from the models file. Make and migrate again. Once the column has been removed from the db, delete both migration files(the ones you created for adding and deleting the column).